# How do I fix the "Fatal error 605" on SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, fatal-error

Code that was working fine last week is suddenly throwing this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Warning: Fatal error
>   605 occurred at [date / time]. Note the error and time, and contact
>   your system administrator.

We are running .NET Framework 4.0 on SQL Server 2008 R2 and this exception is thrown while running a stored procedure.

Comment: You have database corruption. Look at http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/05/10/77863.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917590.aspx for solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end all we had to do was to make sure all the Service Packs and Cumulative Updates were installed on the SQL servers.